# R unique expressions

Tags: r, expression

I am using the [gramEvol package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gramEvol/) to generate expressions which are then used for further data processing.

Sometimes, the result contains duplicate expressions.

How can I retain only the unique expressions? (using unique function does not work as it is not defined for expressions)

Here is a reproducible example that demonstrates the issue:

```
data("iris")
expr <- sapply(colnames(iris), as.expression)
expr
#expression(Sepal.Length = "Sepal.Length", Sepal.Width = "Sepal.Width", 
#    Petal.Length = "Petal.Length", Petal.Width = "Petal.Width", 
#    Species = "Species")
unique(expr)
#Error in unique.default(expr) : 
#  unimplemented type 'expression' in 'HashTableSetup'
expr <- c(expr, expr) # concat works
expr
#expression(Sepal.Length = "Sepal.Length", Sepal.Width = "Sepal.Width", 
#    Petal.Length = "Petal.Length", Petal.Width = "Petal.Width", 
#    Species = "Species", Sepal.Length = "Sepal.Length", Sepal.Width = #"Sepal.Width", Petal.Length = "Petal.Length", Petal.Width = "Petal.Width", 
#    Species = "Species")
unique(expr)
#Error in unique.default(expr) : 
#  unimplemented type 'expression' in 'HashTableSetup'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turns the expression into a list and uses `duplicated`:

```
expr[!duplicated(as.list(expr))]
#expression(Sepal.Length = "Sepal.Length", Sepal.Width = "Sepal.Width", 
#    Petal.Length = "Petal.Length", Petal.Width = "Petal.Width", 
#    Species = "Species")
```